# Size Class - Strange behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, size-classes

If Any UIElements added into the size classes, then the subViews will not be the part of subViews of parent view till its get loaded.

[image]

Code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     NSLog(@"sub VIews %@", self.view.subviews);

}
```

Result :

> 2015-02-13 13:52:16.113 TestAutolayout[1619:42189] sub VIews (
>       "<_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fcc8bd9ded0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = >",
>       "<_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fcc8bd9eb60; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = >" )

Once its loaded, tried on button event: 
Code :

```
- (IBAction)btnTest:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"sub VIews %@", self.view.subviews);

}
```

Result :

[image]

**So the question is, Why view.subViews is not drawn till its get loaded?**.

*Note :* If we added the UIElements at any:any size class its working fine .

Comment: I've got the same issue. Is there any official solution out by now or are you still using the layoutIfNeeded() workaround posted below?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by forcing to draw the UIElements by using `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]`, before its get loaded.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     NSLog(@"sub VIews %@", self.view.subviews);

}
```

Might be the reason for performance effectiveness.